# .Net Matrix

Tags: .net, matrix

Is there a standard .Net matrix class? I cannot find it if there is.

If not, why not? It sounds like something people would need very frequently. Are there any non-standard libs you could recommend?

Answer (score 2):

The XNA Framework has a Matrix structure. I'm not aware of any part of the main framework that has a Matrix class though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is, partially because any array can technically be called a "Matrix" if it is a single dimension array of length n, it is an n x 1 matrix.  There is also the question of whether you'd want the matrix to hold integers, doubles, or other numerical values that may play a role in some Matrix functions.

There do exist various places like [here](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/) and [here](http://www.centerspace.net/products.php) that may bundle some Matrix classes with other Linear Algebra functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a Matrix class in the [Lydos.MatLab library](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~alexk/lydos.matlab.html) ([documentation](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~alexk/lydos.matlab.doc/index.html)), which is distributed as open source project under the [zlib/libpng license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/zlib-license.php).

Example usage in C#:

```
using Lydos.Matlab;
using System;

public class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Engine e = new Engine();
        Matrix m = new Matrix(2, 2), n;

        m[0, 0] = 0;
        m[0, 1] = 1;
        m[1, 0] = 2;
        m[1, 1] = 3;

        e.SetMatrix("m", m);
        e.Evaluate("m = m + 1");
        n = e.GetMatrix("m");

        Console.WriteLine(m); // [0 1; 2 3]
        Console.WriteLine(n); // [1 2; 3 4]

        m.Dispose();
        n.Dispose();
        e.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this library performs interop to Matlab, which may rule it out in many cases.